# How can I convert AJAX into angular js and repeat the code block for each element of an array?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I want create a system where a section of code from an external text file is imported and repeated using angular js. The code needs to run through a number of text files and create a new section for each I have been attempting to rewrite my ajax code from a previous problem in angular js and I cannot seem to find a way to make it work. That problem can be found here: [Calling angularjs inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203188/calling-angularjs-inside).

My old AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '../src/text/section1.txt',
    dataType: 'text',
    success : function (data) {
        $('#section1').append(data);
    },
});
```

This is what I have currently:

```
app.controller('sectionController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.sections = [
    {id: 1, title: 'Page 1', data: ''},
    {id: 2, title: 'Page 2', data: ''},
    {id: 3, title: 'Page 3', data: ''},
    {id: 4, title: 'Page 4', data: ''},
    {id: 5, title: 'Page 5', data: ''},];

  angular.forEach($scope.sections, function(id) {
    $http({
      url : '../../src/text/section' + $scope.sections.id +'.txt',
      dataType: 'text',
    }).success(function (data) {
      $scope.sections[id].data = data;
    });
  });
}]);
```

My HTML is:

```
<div class="body">
            <div class="bodyBackground"></div>
            <div class="contentContainer" ng-controller="sectionController">
                <div id="sectionContainer" ng-repeat="section in sections">
                    <div id="section{{ section.id }}">
                        <h3 class="sectionTitle">{{ section.title }}</h3>
                        <div>{{ section.data }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Ok? What's the problem?

Comment: Suggest you study some angular tutorials that show you how to use roting and how to use model data to render the view. `document.querySelector('#section' + id)` is the wrong approach . What is the higher level overview of what a `page` is in your data? And what is in the text files?

Comment: The text files contain text wrapped in <p> tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider adding a 'data' property to your $scope.sections objects

```
$scope.sections = [
{id: 1, title: 'page 1', data: ''}
]
```

then in the success of your HTTP set the response data to the appropriate section object data property

```
  }).success(function (data) {
      section.data = data;
    });
```

and in your HTML Bind to the data property of the section object

```
    app.controller('sectionController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.sections = [
        {id: 1, title: 'Page 1', data: ''},
        {id: 2, title: 'Page 2', data: ''},
        {id: 3, title: 'Page 3', data: ''},
        {id: 4, title: 'Page 4', data: ''},
        {id: 5, title: 'Page 5', data: ''}];

    angular.forEach($scope.sections, function(section) {
        $http({
            url : '../../src/text/section' + section.id +'.txt',
            dataType: 'text'
        }).success(function (data) {
            section.data = data;
        });
    });
}]);
```

Comment: I have edited my code to reflect your suggestions but it is still not functional. Have I missed anything?

Comment: a couple of issues with how you were referencing the section in the forEach, i renamed id to section to be more clear and adjusted the references.  also missing annotation for injection of $http